# Powershell: cannot access the local farm

Tags: 2010, powershell

Yes, I am logged into the machine as an administrator, and my domain account id a farm admin as well.  The site is running properly, and nothing seems wrong in SP Central Administration.
But when I start powershell, I get "Cannot access the local farm"

Also, running powershell with admin rights.

Where do I start to diagnose this issue?

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: This issue may also occur if there is a new .Net framework update applied and affect the Power Shell version. more details at  **[The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/)**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found it.  My account needed proper rights in SQL Server, per this post:

[The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/)

It worked once I set `"Sharepoint_Shell_Access"` to the `Sharepoint_Config` database.

What got me here was searching for the first message:  "the local farm is not accessible"

Comment: You should mark your own answer (with the check mark)

Comment: ah, would do so, but need to wait 2 days for some reason.  odd

Comment: this is so people dont just boost their rep answering their own questions :-)

Comment: Also remember UAC can be an issue here. Check my blog post on that issue http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sharepoint_shell_access-role-on-a-content-database/

Answer (score 18):

Perform the following script in the SharePoint Management Shell, as a farm administrator and it will remove the error.

```
Get-SPDatabase | Add-SPShellAdmin SomeDomain\SomeUserName
```

This will grant the user both access to the configuration database as well as the content database.

Alternatively, you can revoke that granted access with the opposite command.

```
Get-SPDatabase | Remove-SPShellAdmin SomeDomain\SomeUserName
```

Answer (score 8):

I know you are a farm admin, but try right clicking on Powershell, and select 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: Vote up for this. Also, the user may need to be in the local WSS_Admin_WPG group.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your PowerShell version is incompatible with the SharePoint Management Shell (commandlets).

Use below command to change the version used:

```
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\PowerShell.exe -version 2.0 -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1' "
```

Add `–version 2.0 switch;`

Answer (score 3):

In my case this was caused by my administrative user account not being in the list of users under the server. It used to be there, but it was mysteriously missing.

[image]

To make this more interesting, I added my user in manually to the server and it had all of the User Mapping already applied without my doing anything. It's almost as if some process kicked it off of the list but the databases kept the mapping.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes running as administrator does not work if the administrator does not have proper database / shell permissions, either. In that case, hold down shift and right-click on the PowerShell icon. Choose to run as a different user and run PowerShell as the farm account. Now you should be able to use Quinn Johns' answer to grant shell access to other accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

> The local farm is not accessible

But after restart and repeating `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` it worked perfectly.