# How to add User as Farm Admin

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint web part (deployed on a SharePoint 2007 server) to a new SharePoint 2010 server. I am connected to it via Remote Desktop Connection. When I run (as admin) Windows PowerShell the first thing it tells me is that "The local farm is not accessible." I read that I need to run PowerShell as an admin and make sure I add my user account to the farm admin group. How do I do that?

Are there other steps I need to take as well? I am new to this, so I don't know where everything is.

Comment: which version of sharepoint you using ?

Comment: Also make sure that you are running PowerShell as administrator. Right-Click -> Run As Administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the logged in user who is trying to run SharePoint PowerShell commands is having the right "SharePoint_Shell_Access" to the SharePoint_Configuration database to do so.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/18/sharepoint-powershell-command-problem-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx

OR using command

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20399.sharepoint-2013-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx

Or

[Suddenly getting "The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/suddenly-getting-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependen)

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer. None of the articles I Googled ever detailed how to do this. Unfortunately, it's telling me that "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'Solution'". But that's another issue. I also ran Add-SPShellAdmin and that says the local farm is still not accessible. What's going on?

Comment: U didnt answer my question , which versiom of sp ?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/suddenly-getting-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependen

Comment: SP Server 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running powershell or sharepoint management shell?
Can you access Central Admin? If not you have a problem with your farm topology if you can then try running SharePoint management shell instead it may be that your version of vanilla powershell in missing the necessery snapins to connect to sharepoint.

Comment: So use SharePoint Management Shell, and do everything as I would normally on PowerShell?

Comment: Exactly. As a general practice I use SharePoint Management Shell for anything involving SharePoint.